# How to show text in drawable custom marker

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to create a Custom Marker that displays text with a number equal to the example below:

### Example:

### [image]

But when you run the application the text is not displayed, only the red ellipse appears without a number.

## My Code

### InicializeMap()##

```
 private void InicializeMap() 
{
    if (_googleMap == null) 
    {
        _googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapMapeamento)).getMap();

        LatLng pos = new LatLng(23.4555453556, 11.145315551);

        MapUtils mapUtils = new MapUtils(getApplicationContext());
        Bitmap bitmap = mapUtils.GetBitmapMarker();

        Marker marker = _googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(pos)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap)));

        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (_googleMap == null) 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Mensagens.erroCriarMapa, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

---

### My method to create the Bitmap

```
public Bitmap GetBitmapMarker()
{
    Paint color = new Paint();
    color.setTextSize(35);
    color.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    int px = _mContext.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.map_dot_marker_size);

    Bitmap mDotMarkerBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(px, px, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mDotMarkerBitmap);
    canvas.drawText("Hello!", 30, 40, color);

    Drawable shape = _mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape_marker_red);

    shape.setBounds(0, 0, mDotMarkerBitmap.getWidth(), mDotMarkerBitmap.getHeight());
    shape.draw(canvas);

    return mDotMarkerBitmap;
}
```

### res/drawable/shape_marker_red

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" >
    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:endColor="#f58383"
        android:startColor="#ee6464" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#a13939" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got the following implementation and it worked. 
The implementation was as follows:

MapActivity class

```
MapUtils mapUtils = new MapUtils(getApplicationContext());
        Bitmap bitmap = mapUtils.GetBitmapMarker(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.marker_blue, "1");

        Marker marker = _googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(pos)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap)));
```

MapUtils Class

```
public Bitmap GetBitmapMarker(Context mContext, int resourceId,  String mText) 
{
    try 
    {
        Resources resources = mContext.getResources();
        float scale = resources.getDisplayMetrics().density;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, resourceId);

        android.graphics.Bitmap.Config bitmapConfig = bitmap.getConfig();

        // set default bitmap config if none
        if(bitmapConfig == null)
          bitmapConfig = android.graphics.Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

        bitmap = bitmap.copy(bitmapConfig, true);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setTextSize((int) (14 * scale));
        paint.setShadowLayer(1f, 0f, 1f, Color.DKGRAY);

        // draw text to the Canvas center
        Rect bounds = new Rect();
        paint.getTextBounds(mText, 0, mText.length(), bounds);
        int x = (bitmap.getWidth() - bounds.width())/2;
        int y = (bitmap.getHeight() + bounds.height())/2;

        canvas.drawText(mText, x * scale, y * scale, paint);

        return bitmap;

    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {           
        return null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hey this creates a very huge marker . Any idea what can this be?

Comment: It will depend on the size of the marker you have, the id of that marker is reported in the GetBitmapMarker method as "int resourceID"
If you want to create your own marker in a size that is proportional to each device, I suggest you use this tool.
https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html

Comment: In the GetBitmapMarker method (...) do not forget to adjust the size of the text in paint.SetTextSize ((int) (10 * scale)).

Answer (score 23):

This is what I came up with.

[image]

First, declare your marker options to add the marker on the map.

```
MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(GlobalApp.getInstance().getLoginUserInfo().getLatitude(),
                                GlobalApp.getInstance().getLoginUserInfo().getLongitude()))
                        .draggable(false)
                        .flat(false)
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(createStoreMarker()));
                Marker tempMarker = globalGoogleMap.addMarker(options);
```

Add a function to inflate a layout of your specification and you can get their reference and add whatever you want.This is the place where the magic happens.

```
private Bitmap createStoreMarker() {
        View markerLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.store_marker_layout, null);

        ImageView markerImage = (ImageView) markerLayout.findViewById(R.id.marker_image);
        TextView markerRating = (TextView) markerLayout.findViewById(R.id.marker_text);
        markerImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_home_marker);
        markerRating.setText(GlobalApp.getInstance().getLoginUserInfo().getStoreName());

        markerLayout.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        markerLayout.layout(0, 0, markerLayout.getMeasuredWidth(), markerLayout.getMeasuredHeight());

        final Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(markerLayout.getMeasuredWidth(), markerLayout.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        markerLayout.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    }
```

This is the layout

> store_marker_layout.xml
>   I am inflating

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_store_marker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/marker_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="dgdfgdfg"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/marker_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_home_marker" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I don't know why this is not the correct answer, works like a charm!

Comment: this is the only solution worked for me on kotlin on 2023 as per the latest library versions

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. In this method, we're creating the BitmapDescriptor with a lap number centered into one of 3 drawables.

```
/**
 * @param lapNbr String
 * @return {@link BitmapDescriptor}
 */
private BitmapDescriptor createLapBitMap(String lapNbr) {
    // Determine which of the 3 icons to start from. 1 being the thinnest, 3 being the widest.
    Bitmap tmp = null;
    switch (lapNbr.length()) {
        case 1:
            tmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.lap_icon1);
            break;
        case 2:
            tmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.lap_icon2);
            break;
        // If a dude is recording more than 999 laps, let's just shoot him. :)
        default:
            tmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.lap_icon3);
            break;
    }

    if (tmp != null) {
        Bitmap.Config config = tmp.getConfig();
        if (config == null) {
            config = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        }
        // Resource bitmpas are immutable, so we need to convert it to a mutable one.
        Bitmap bm = tmp.copy(config, true);
        if (bm != null) {
            // Draw text to the canvas center.
            Rect bounds = new Rect();
            mLapIconPaint.getTextBounds(lapNbr, 0, lapNbr.length(), bounds);
            int x = (bm.getWidth() - bounds.width()) / 2;
            int y = ((bm.getHeight() + bounds.height()) / 2) - 10; // bump it up just a bit
            Canvas c = new Canvas(bm);
            c.drawText(lapNbr, x, y, mLapIconPaint);
            return BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bm);
        }
    }

    // Return a default bitmap with a lap circle inside of the icon.
    return BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.lap_icon1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a Bitmap here?  It looks like a drawable will get the job done, and then you could programmatically change the .setText() of each variable depending on the assignment of the marker.

For example:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/markerButton"
    android:background="@drawable/markerDrawable"/>
```

Then:

```
markerButton.setText("1");
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this is now available in the [Google Maps SDK for Android Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility)